# Expo FileSystem.readAsStringAsync could not read file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, filesystems, expo

I have the following setup, when user take picture using ImagePicker it will save it to `FileSystem.documentDirectory` using the following piece of code:

```
saveAvatar = async (uri) => {
   await Expo.FileSystem.moveAsync({
   from: uri,
   to: Expo.FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'avatar/profile'
  })
}

_takePhoto = async () => {
  const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    allowsEditing: false,
    base64: true,
    quality: 0.4
  });

  if (!result.cancelled) {
    this.setState({ image: result.base64 });
    this.saveAvatar(result.uri)
  }
};
```

Then I tried checking retrieving it using this:

```
ensureDirAsync = async () => {
    const props = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'avatar/');

    if (props.exists && props.isDirectory) {
        return props;
    }

    try {
        await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'avatar/', { intermediates: true });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    return await this.ensureDirAsync()
}

getAvatar = async () => {
    let dir = await this.ensureDirAsync(),
        filename = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(dir.uri),
        data = null;
    const props = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(dir.uri + filename[0])
    console.log(props)
    try {
        data = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'avatar/profile');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    console.log(data)
    return data;
}
```

The weird thing is, `const props = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(dir.uri + filename[0])` is printing this:

```
Object {
 "exists": 1,
 "isDirectory": false,
 "modificationTime": 1532930978,
 "size": 399861,
 "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9D3661AF-8EB5-49F5-A178-3ECA0F96BEEC/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FWAMS-1163fc3b-4484-44a2-9076-b4b71df1e55c/avatar/profile",
}
```

Which should indicate that the image was saved successfully, but `data = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(dir.uri + filename[0]);` OR `data = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'avatar/profile')` would give me this error:

`File 'file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9D3661AF-8EB5-49F5-A178-3ECA0F96BEEC/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FWAMS-1163fc3b-4484-44a2-9076-b4b71df1e55c/avatar/profile' could not be read.`

Any idea how could this happen? can `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync()` even read the file I moved from `ImagePicker`? if not, what should I have used instead?

I'm trying this on IOS.

Thanks in advance for the help :smiley:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

got it! turns out instead of moving the file using `FileSystem.moveAsync()` I just have to save the `base64` representation as normal string using `FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync()` and it solved the problem for me

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify the EncodingType. `FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64` works for ***audio/image*** files.

example:

```
content = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });
```